# DISPLAY: GRID with variable height cards creates gaps between rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm using the code at the bottom to create a responsive grid with cards. Each card has a different height because of it's contents. This results in gaps between rows which are very ugly to look at, as shown in the video linked. How can I remove the gaps while maintaining responsiveness?

```
<div class="container">
    {#each data.combinedArray as server}
    <ServerCard data="{server}"/>
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(18.75rem, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 1rem;}
</style>
```

[**Video of gaps & responsiveness**](https://i.imgur.com/Sjk9sQg.mp4)

**EDIT:** I notice this question has been auto-closed with a reply leading to a `grid-template-rows: masonry;` solution. However, this is only experimental and no browser officially supports it, so I'm still looking for a lightweight solution.